# combine elements of an array in pairs ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have a array that looks like this:

```
booklist = [000A,000B,000C]
```

I would like to combine all elements in pairs so that this is the output array:

```
combinedbooks = [000A|000B, 000A|000C, 000B|000C]
```

what I have done is the following:

```
combinedbooks= Array.new
    for i in 0..booklist.length
        for j in i+1..booklist.length                  
            combinedbooks.push(booklist(i) + "|" + booklist(j))
        end
    end
```

Its not working and I have no idea why

Comment: the desired result should be strings? As so: `["000A|000B", "000A|000C", "000B|000C"]`.

Comment: yes, I just need a way to combine it in pairs and save it in a array so that I can later measure the times the combination appears ( I have several booklists and Ill have several combinedbooks that I will merge and count)

Comment: In both `for` statements you need three, rather than two, dots. A more Ruby-like way is to use the methods `Array#combination` followed by `Enumerable#map`.

Comment: In future, consider waiting awhile before selecting an answer. There's no rush. A quick-draw checkmark can discourage other, possibly better answers and is IMO is a discourtesy to those still preparing answers. If you were offered three gifts and liked the first, would you choose it before hearing what the other two were?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually two problems with your code as written. The first is that specific elements of arrays should be referenced with brackets `[]`, not parentheses `()`. The second is that, since Arrays in Ruby are zero-indexed, `list[list.length]` does not exist (`list[list.length-1]` is the last element in the array). If we fix these two problems, you end up with:

```
booklist = ["000A", "000B", "000C"]

combinedbooks = Array.new
for i in 0..booklist.length-1
  for j in i+1..booklist.length-1
    combinedbooks.push(booklist[i] + "|" + booklist[j])
  end
end
```

Which works as you intended.

Ruby is a pretty powerful language though, so there's actually a much simpler way of doing what you want using a combination of the [`combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-combination), [`map`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-join) methods on [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html):

```
booklist = ["000A", "000B", "000C"]
combinedbooks = booklist.combination(2).map{|combination| combination.join("|")}
```

Comment: Best answer, IMO, because you both explain the problem and show the better way, and do both very nicely.

Comment: How would the code change if I want to add a one to each combination [000A|000B, 1] ?

Comment: You mean the "shorter, simpler way"? Just change the block given to `map` so that it returns that array instead of just the book ids. So that would be `[combination.join("|"), 1]` instead of `combination.join("|")`. You might want to consider reading the documentation I linked to if you don't understand the shorter example.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to your nested for loops is to use [`#combination`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-combination):

```
[25] pry(main)> booklist
=> ["000A", "000B", "000C"]
[26] pry(main)> booklist.combination(2).map { |i| i.join("|") }
=> ["000A|000B", "000A|000C", "000B|000C"]
```

Comment: Replace the `.to_a` with `.map { |book_pair| book_pair.join('|') }` and you have the OP's desired end result

Comment: @TheChamp: Yes. In addition `.combination` is an `Enumerator`, so can be used to work through possibilities with a low memory footprint when there are e.g. thousands of entries (although for the OP's problem, wanting to use as a label for a stats bucket, this is not an issue)

Comment: nice +1 to this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```
booklist = ['000A', '000B', '000C']
joined_booklist = []
booklist.each_with_index do |book, i|
   next if i == (booklist.length - 1)
  ((i+1)..(booklist.length-1)).each do |j|
     joined_booklist << book + "|" + booklist[j]
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, the OP used indices, but should we be encouraging that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with an `until loop`

```
booklist = ["000A","000B","000C"]

# duplicate the array
booklist_dup = booklist

result_array = []

until booklist_dup.empty?
  # takes the first element out of the array
  first_el = booklist_dup.shift

  # create a combination with each element of the remaining array
  booklist.each{ |el| result_array << first_el + "|" + el}
end

# => ["000A|000B", "000A|000C", "000B|000C"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Array#combination for that kind of behavior :

```
booklist = ['000A', '000B', '000C']
booklist.combination(2).map { |pair| pair.join('|') }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
booklist = ['000A', '000B', '000C']
pairs = booklist.combination(2).to_a
pairs.map!{|a,b|"#{a}|#{b}"}
```